# writing data to an xml file using an xsd schema in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

I am new to using xml schemas.

I have managed to create a class for my schema using xsd.exe, and I have managed to generate the following code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var MarketDeclaration_detail = new TransactionsPalletsPalletMarketDeclaration { Set = "", Declaration = "" };
    var MarketDeclaration_class = new TransactionsPalletsPalletMarketDeclaration[] { MarketDeclaration_detail };

    var PalletLine_detail = new TransactionsPalletsPalletPalletLine { ProductLineNo = "", Quantity = "" };
    var PalletLine_class = new TransactionsPalletsPalletPalletLine[] { PalletLine_detail };

    var pallet_detail = new TransactionsPalletsPallet { AccreditDate = "", Available = "", Customer = "", MarketDeclaration = MarketDeclaration_class, MixedPltIndicator = "",
                                                        PalletLine = PalletLine_class, PalletNo = "", PalletType = "", PartPltIndicator = "", PltSubmisProfile = "", SLOC = "", Status = "", StorageType = "",
                                                        Trader = "", TransferInNo = "", TransferOutNo = "", TransferOutOrder = "", TransferOutOrderLine = ""};

    var pallet_class = new TransactionsPalletsPallet[] { pallet_detail };

    var Materials_detail = new TransactionsReferencesMaterialsMaterial { MaterialNo = "", Trader = "", Brand = "", Variety = "", Size = "", Pack = "", GrowingMethod = "", Grade = "", PackTreatment = "", MarketAttribute = "", Count =""};
    var Materials_class = new TransactionsReferencesMaterialsMaterial[] { Materials_detail };

    var ProductLines_detail = new TransactionsReferencesProductLinesProductLine { ColourBand = "", Customer = "", ExpiryDate = "", Grower = "", HarvestDate = "", MaterialNo = "", MgmtArea = "", Owner = "", 
                                                                                  PackDate = "", Packer = "", PackWeight = "", ProblemRisk = "", ProductionProgram = "", ProductLineNo = "", RPIN = "", Run = "", 
                                                                                  SGContract = "", SGContractLine = "", Subdivision = "", SubmisProfile = "", SupplyGroup = "", Trader = ""};
    var ProductLines_class = new TransactionsReferencesProductLinesProductLine[] { ProductLines_detail };

    var TransfersOut_detail = new TransactionsReferencesTransfersOutTransfer { CarrierID = "", ContainerNo = "", DestinationPort = "", DischargePort = "", DispatchDate = "", DispatchTime = "", ETA = "", From = "", LoadPort = "", ReleaseNo = "",
                                                                               SealNo = "", Temperature1 = "", Temperature2 = "", TempLogger = "", To = "", TransferNo = "", TransferRef = "", TruckID = "", Vessel = "", Voyage = ""};
    // var TransfersOut_class = new TransactionsReferencesTransfersOutTransfer[] { TransfersOut_detail };
    TransfersOut();

    var references_detail = new TransactionsReferences { Materials = Materials_class, ProductLines = ProductLines_class, TransfersOut = TransfersOut_class };
    var references_class = new TransactionsReferences[] { references_detail };

    var data1 = new Transactions { Pallets = pallet_class, References = references_class, Serialnumber = "", Timestamp = "" };

    var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Transactions));

    using (var stream1 = new StreamWriter("C:\\Dave\\xml\\djb2.xml"))
        serializer1.Serialize(stream1,data1);
}

public static TransactionsReferencesTransfersOutTransfer[] TransfersOut_class;

public static void TransfersOut()
{
    TransactionsReferencesTransfersOutTransfer[] TransfersOut_detail1 = new TransactionsReferencesTransfersOutTransfer[3];            

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       TransfersOut_detail1[i] = new TransactionsReferencesTransfersOutTransfer { CarrierID = Convert.ToString(i) };

       TransfersOut_class = new TransactionsReferencesTransfersOutTransfer[] { TransfersOut_detail1[0], TransfersOut_detail1[1], TransfersOut_detail1[2] };
    }
}
```

Which all works OK.

By question / problem is

With my TransfersOut method I have given the for loop a limit of 3, as I have also with TransferOut_details. However I have NO idea how many there will be until the data is return from the Database. 3 was used as a test.

I am unsure how to code this so I will get all the rows return/write to the XML file.

Any ideas / help would be appreciated.

I am note ever sure if I have coded this in the best way possible.

Comment: We cannot possibly answer without knowing where/how are you going to read your data. If it comes from a DB you'd need code to connect to this DB and read the relevant tables - once you did that the number of objects to create would come automatically from the number of rows you retrieved....

Comment: yes it will be coming from a database.

Yes I know that will give me the number to replace my test 3 with.

What I dont't know is how to

Comment: replace  this line, which I also know should be outside the for loop

   TransfersOut_class = new TransactionsReferencesTransfersOutTransfer[] { TransfersOut_detail1[0], TransfersOut_detail1[1], TransfersOut_detail1[2] };

with a line(s) of code that will pass all the created objects

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it wrong, and have resolved this, however this has generated a new issue I am trying to resolve, which may generate a separate question on Object reference not set to an instance of an object.